# Grails MongoDB Embedded Domain Objects Saving

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

When attempting to save a Grails Domain object that is backed by Mongo all of my embedded objects are having `save()` called on them as well. In some instances this is causing some tremendous affect on performance.

Some example domain objects are as follows.

```
class Bird {
    Object Id
    String name
}

class Nest {
    static embedded = ['birds']

    String name
    Set<Bird> birds
}

class Tree {
    static embedded = ['nests']

    Object Id
    String name
}

class TreeState {
    static embedded = ['tree']

    Object Id
    Set<Nest> nests
    Tree tree
    Date dateCreated
}
```

Now let's say I wanted to save the state of a tree at a given time.

```
def tree = Tree.findByName("Sleepwood")

def nestA = new Nest()
nestA.birds = new LinkedHashSet()
nestA.name = "Sleepwood-A"

def nestB = new Nest()
nestB.birds = new LinkedHashSet()
nestB.name = "Sleepwood-B"

def blueJay = Bird.findByName('Blue Jay')
def cardinal = Bird.findByName('Cardinal')
def oriole = Bird.findByName('Oriole')
def robin = Bird.findByName('Robin')

def treeState =  new TreeState()
treeState.nests =  new LinkedHashSet()
treeState.tree = tree

nestA.add(blueJay)
nestA.add(cardinal)
nestA.add(oriole)

nestB.add(oriole)
nestB.add(blueJay)
nestB.add(robin)

treeState.nests.add(nestA)
treeState.nests.add(nestB)
treeState.safe(failOnError: true)
```

This sort of action seems to cause the embedded entities, `Bird` and `Tree` to be saved as values but also seem to be saved as well to update their associated domain models.

Is there a way I can prohibit these references from being updated and just save the embedded fields in the `TreeState` object?